# Can't seem to print a method in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a simple program that makes a list of words then it picks a random word and then it prints that word. Everything works but I just can't seem to make the program print the word. This is my code so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Hangman

{
    class Program
    {

    List<String> words = new List<String> { "cat", "police", "conjuring", "sand", "hoppleflink", "defenestrait", "cumberground", "sexy shreck" };

    public string PickRandom()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var wordCount = words.Count;
        var randomNum = random.Next(wordCount);
        var randomWord = words[randomNum];
        return randomWord;


    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(); 
    }

}
```

}

Comment: ...Which bit do you think should be printing a word?

Comment: You are not printing the random word anywhere in the code. Also not calling method `PickRandom` anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work, you need to print a value rather than nothing, as you currently are.

At the moment, your `words` field and `PickRandom` method are instance members, so `Main` (a static method) cannot use them without an instance of `Program`. So, first, we'll create an instance of Program:

```
Program program = new Program();
```

Then we'll take a random word:

```
string word = program.PickRandom();
```

And finally we'll write it:

```
Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Putting it all together:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program program = new Program();
    string word = program.PickRandom();
    Console.WriteLine(word); 
    // keep the console open after the code has executed by waiting for a keypress
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

You can read about static vs instance members [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).

You'll probably run up against an issue with `Random` soon - if you call your `PickRandom` method too frequently, you'll find that you get the same value repeated. The reason why is explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number). TL;DR: The seed value is based on time, so if you create two instances of `Random`at the exact same time, you'll get the same seed value.